# Passing number variable through CasperJS command line leads to some character instead of the number

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have a basic CasperJS script, that inserts a pre-defined search term in to the amazon search box, and when I execute the script and look at the captured image I can see the text in the box fine.

I then decided to make it dynamic and instead of pre-defining the search term I pass it though the command line like so.

```
casperjs amazon.js --barcode=4380758484375
```

However, when I do this I get no text in the search field on the amazon site when I look at the captured image. I know the value is being passed as I have echo'ed it.

My experience with very limited and started learning this weekend, I'm wondering if I need to define the var at all. For testing purposes barcode is set to the value being passed through the command line, and barcode1 is pre-defined.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)');


casper.echo("Casper CLI passed args:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.args);

casper.echo("Casper CLI passed options:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.options);


var barcode = casper.cli.get("barcode");
var barcode1 = "5030945112877"; //casper.cli.get("barcode");


casper.echo("*"+barcode1+"*");


casper.start('https://www.amazon.co.uk/');

casper.then(function () {
    this.sendKeys('#twotabsearchtextbox', barcode);
    console.log('Entering Search Term '+barcode+' Into Amazon Search Field');
    casper.capture('amazon.png');
});

casper.run();
```

If I set `--barcode=fifa` it works. If I set it to `--barcode=fifa123` it also works, but if I set it to `--barcode=123`, in the capture image I see an extended char corresponding to the 123.

Comment: i have CasperJS 1.1.1 and PhantomJS 1.9.8 running on Raspberry Pi. Still same problem and for the life of me cant work it out.

Comment: I've even tried it with CasperJS 1.1.1 and PhantomJS 1.9.7 on my Raspberry Pi 1. It works. What exactly is not working for you? I see the thing I pass in in the screenshot. Note that the first `echo` in your code is for `barcode1` and not `barcode`

Comment: i think i have found the problem, if i set --barcode=fifa it works, if i set it to --barcode=fifa123 it also works, but if i set it to --barcode=123 in the capture image i see an extended char appose to the 123 , so wondering if i have to define var barcode some how

Comment: i think for some reason if i only pass a number through the command line its treating it as an int or val appose to a string. so what i did was stick a letter 'a' at the beginning like this 'a5030945112877' and then did .substring(1) to remove the letter leaving only the number which worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

See [**Raw parameter values**](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html):

> By default, the cli object will process every passed argument & cast them to the appropriate detected type[...]

CasperJS automatically parses CLI options into appropriate types. If you type in a number, it will be converted to a number. This is not problematic as-is, but since this number is passed into `casper.sendKeys()` it is not treated as a string. `casper.sendKeys()` is a wrapper around PhantomJS' [`page.sendEvent()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html), which treats integers are [char codes](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/cab2635e66d74b7e665c44400b8b20a8f225153a).

You need to use the raw value or convert to string yourself:

```
var barcode = casper.cli.raw.get("barcode");
// or
var barcode = "" + casper.cli.get("barcode");
```

Answer (score 1):

after a bit of trail and error it seems passing a number only through the command line is where the problem exists.

by using

```
casper.cli.raw.get("barcode");
```

instead of

```
casper.cli.get("barcode");
```

resolved the problem, this is due to a chance in the CasperJS version that i can see. Also found reference to the following site https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/248